# Use regex to delete the beginning of a line stopping n characters from the end of a string

Tags: notepad++, regex

I've tried a few different regex strings in Notepad++, but can't figure out the lookahead part to make this work. I have a few thousand lines of text and am trying to remove the variable number of characters and leave a fixed number of them from the end of the line. Examples:

Input:

```
alhsoidoli aoisudoifu oaisoi
iodaoiu a;osidh ;oaiyu ;oisdlhidadsli
LOIHYoihdlhi OIHlohi LOHIOOLhiol oo
```

Output:

```
ifu oaisoi
dlhidadsli
OOLhiol oo
```

So the find criteria would match the last 10 characters from the end and preserve that, deleting the entire rest of the line. I don't have any special delimiting character I can match on; every line is very different. The only thing I do know is the fixed number of characters from the end of the line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*(?=.{10}$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  .*              # 0 or more any character but newline
  (?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    .{10}           # exactly 10 any character
    $               # end of line
  )               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: @KeithWood: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)